# nodejs how to make a folder path discoverable globally from any sub-dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, path

Im creating a tool that lets users create directories. The directory names will be vary for each user. There will be a root 'config' folder in the parent created directory.

So it could look something like this:

- MyFolder

  - config
  - otherFolder1
  - otherFolder2

    - subFolder1

I need that config folder path discoverable no matter what sub-directory im in but not discoverable in any parent dir above 'MyFolder'. I had the idea of saving the parent 'MyFolder' path upon initialization BUT then i run into an issue if they change the name of 'MyFolder'

Comment: You could check for changes in `MyFolder/..`, although that could become impractical for large directories, it is the least directory-traversal method available (e.g. checking each parent directory for a `config` folder)

Comment: What does "config folder path discoverable" mean?  And, it's really not practical to say you want to keep track of a folder path when the parent names can be renamed at any time.  Unless you're going to have some root folder that never changes name and then you're going to search the entire hierarchy to find what your looking for when you need it (which would be inefficient if it's a large file hierarchy).

Comment: im wondering how git is able to do it. you can call its functions which read the content in the .git folder from any subdirectory in your repo (even if u change the name of the parent directories). the config folder here would be the equivalent the .git folder in ur repos